# jQuery-like library for learning purposes

Tags: javascript, library

I am attempting to build a small JavaScript library (similar to jQuery)

The purpose behind this is mostly a learning exercise, so asking why I don't just use an existing library is moot.

So far I have just got my basic constructor, a 'caller' function to invoke a new object, and some basic functions for an example.

```
var lemon = function() {
    var prop = {
        collection: []
    };
    var fn = {
        init: function(selector, context) {
            context = context || document;
            if (!selector) {
                return;
            } else if (typeof selector == "string") {
                prop.collection = fn.toArray(context.querySelectorAll(selector));
            } else if (selector instanceof Array || selector instanceof NodeList) {
                fn.toArray(selector).forEach(function(obj) {
                    prop.collection.push(obj);
                });
            } else if (selector instanceof Element) {
                prop.collection.push(selector);
            }
            prop.length = prop.collection.length;
            fn.extend.apply(this, [this, prop, fn]);
        },
        toArray: function(target) {
            var array = [];
            for (var i = target.length >>> 0; i--;) {
                array[i] = target[i];
            }
            return array;
        },
        extend: function(target) {
            var objects = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            objects.forEach(function(obj) {
                var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
                props.forEach(function(key) {
                    target[key] = obj[key];
                });
            });
            return target;
        },
        addClass: function(klass) {
            for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
                this.collection[i].className += " " + klass;
            }
            return this;
        }
    };
    fn.init.apply(this, fn.toArray(arguments));
};
var $ = function(selector, context) {
    return new lemon(selector, context);
};
```

Comment: Why is your API identical to jQuery. Why not sit down and think what you need for this javascript library.

Comment: I have sat down and thought of what i need, and it's 1/8th of jQuery. so i'm basically building the functionality I need and basing it off of jQuery user-end look and feel. *without all of the bloat, or trying*

Comment: @rlemon There is a reason for the jQuery Bloat/'try'-ing It would be good to first find out why this is such a bloat to you. If you use the minified files jQuery is quite small and then just put good expires headers when you serve them or link to a CDN. Otherwise things like you are doing can get quite tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is quite a performance problem with your code: it will rebuild the `fn` object and all its methods every time the `lemon(selector, context)` constructor gets called. You can avoid that behavior by using the module design pattern:

```
this.lemon = (function () {

    var fn = {
    /* The code for the fn object here
        init: function (selector, context) {
            var prop = this.prop;
            ...
    */

    return function lemon() {
        this.prop = {
            collection: []
        };
        fn.init.apply(this, fn.toArray(arguments));
    };

 })();
```

However, you will have to add a line `var prop = this.prop;` in the beginning of every method of the `fn` object that requires `prop`.

Also, when introducing a new global variable, it is better for the readability of your code to use `this.myVar = myValue;` or `window.myVar = myValue;`. In fact, the `var` keyword should only be used for local variables.

Finally, it is often recommended to put a space between the `function` keyword and the following parenthesis, but that's not mandatory.

Comment: that spacing was due to jsfiddle 'tidyup' function ;) and I noticed that performance improvement. So I have actually implemented a version of what you have noted :)

Comment: I'm glad to help you... Keep up the good work!